# xls2csv skipping bool values when converting

Tags: linux, csv, ubuntu, xls

I'm attempting to use catdoc -> xls2csv on an Ubuntu 14.04.1 OS to convert and .xls file to a .csv file. All of the values are converting correctly except in the last column which contain TRUE/FALSE values.

I've attempted to add columns before and after with multiple types of input data and it all is recognized except for the TRUE/FALSE values which are left blank

Example entry in XLS

> `Id  Site       Name IsCustomer 
>   123 google.com eric TRUE`

Output in CSV

> `Id  Site       Name IsCustomer
>   123,google.com,eric,,`

Comment: This is off-topic for SO as it is about using a command-line utility, not programming.  It belongs on [su]

Comment: Great, thanks Jim for clarifying.